# React Native Woocommerce REST API throws error on localhost

Tags: react-native, woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api, woocommerce-rest-api

I am using the Woocommerce REST API library `@woocommerce/woocommerce-rest-api` in my React native e-commerce app. I have also tried out the library https://github.com/JamesUgbanu/react-native-woocommerce-api. I am testing this on `localhost:8080`.

In `AndroidManifest.xml`, the `android:usesCleartextTraffic` attribute is set to `"true"`.

Both the aforementioned libraries generate the URL as such

```
http://localhost:8080/wp-json/wc/v3/products?oauth_consumer_key=ck_d1e9172ffce8f4016a3ae9b1ee8bce8b7a4c6365&oauth_nonce=ajJA9q13HYyZJU2TRMIqaeYU3vq1I1DP&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA256&oauth_timestamp=1611684425&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=MEh5Rb72foVJtC6k8E9GsV6DeExMF%2BDyKK0CcRC4EeM%3D
```

The API call from the React Native app shows a status code of `0` and no response.

When I copy the generated URL and run the API from the browser (simply pasting the URL into the address bar), the call is successful and the response contains the expected data.

When I cURL from the terminal though, it throws 401 error.

```
curl -H "accept:application/json" -H "user-agent:WooCommerce REST API - JS Client/1.0.1" http://localhost:8080/wp-json/wc/v3/products?oauth_consumer_key=ck_d1e9172ffce8f4016a3ae9b1ee8bce8b7a4c6365&oauth_nonce=ajJA9q13HYyZJU2TRMIqaeYU3vq1I1DP&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA256&oauth_timestamp=1611684425&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=MEh5Rb72foVJtC6k8E9GsV6DeExMF%2BDyKK0CcRC4EeM%3D


{"code":"woocommerce_rest_authentication_missing_parameter","message":"Missing OAuth parameters oauth_timestamp, oauth_nonce, oauth_signature, oauth_signature_method","data":{"status":401}}
```

What's going on? Why such varying responses from different sources? Above all, how do I get the response in the app?

Comment: Did you try using `-d` option and pass the data there instead of making it part of url itself ?

Comment: But it's working from the browser. I'm most concerned about making it work from the app rather than cURL.

Answer (score 1):

The Word 'localhost' is a reserved word for android. Replace localhost with your pc's ip address and it should work fine on android emulator.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are facing similar issues, do check if you are making your request on http or https. Add s if it is http.